# The Structure of the Galois Group of $K/F$ inside $GL_n(F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

This question is in two parts. In the first, I give my thoughts and ask for verification that they are correct or whether there are closely related ideas that would improve this intuitive picture. In the second I ask a question related to these thoughts.

PART 1:
Suppose we have a degree n Galois extension $K/F$ of fields. Then $K/F$ is an n-dimensional $F$ vector space. Thus, if we pick a basis$ v_1, ..., v_n$ of $K/F$, then we have a ring hom $ K \hookrightarrow M_n(F)$ given by $k \mapsto M_k$ where $M_k$ is the matrix giving the action of multiplication by $k$ on $v_1, ..., v_n$. In particular, that means the field K embeds into $M_n(F)$ for any such $K$. Additionally, we have a group map $T: K^* \to GL_n(F)$.

The elements of the Galois group $G$ are also $F$-linear and so with the above basis, we have a map $S: G \hookrightarrow GL_n(F) \subset M_n(F)$. Now, if we take the matrix $M_k$ but change the basis of $K/F$ to $g(v_1), ..., g(v_n)$, then we see that $M_k$ acts by multiplication by $g(k)$. Thus, ${M_g}^{-1} M_k M_g=M_{g(k)}$ so that $g$ acts by conjugation in $GL_n(F)$. So $S(G)$ is inside the normalizer of $T(K^*)$. Denote the normalizer of $T(K^*)$ in $GL_n(F)$ by $N$.

Now suppose that $\sigma \in N$ acts by conjugation on $K^*$. Then this gives an automorphism of $K^*$. Moreover, considering all these matrices as inside $M_n(F)$ for the moment, we see that the conjugation action will respect addition as well. Thus, the action of $\sigma$ gives an autmorphism of $K$ and therefore there must be some $g \in S(G)$ that gives the same action as $\sigma$.

Thus, we should consider the conjugation action of $N$ on $T(K^*)$. What is the stabilizer of this action? It is the elements of $N$ that commute with $T(K^*)$, i.e, the centralizer of $T(K^*)$.

Now lets consider the centralizer of $T(K^*)$. Note that $T(K^*)$ is Abelian and so contained in its centralizer. But $M \in GL_n(F)$ and $M$ commutes with $T(K^*)$, then in particular, for the vector $v$ corresponding to $1 \in K^*$, we have $kM(v)=M_kM(v)=MM_kv=M(kv)$. So that $M$ is actually $K$-linear. The $K$-linear transformations are actually ismorphic to $K$, and so are an $n$-dimensional $F$-space. Thus, the centralizer of $T(K^*)$ is an $n$-dimensional $F$-space, containing $T(K^*)$ which is already $n$-dimensional! So the centralizer is just $T(K^*)$.

Thus, $T(K^*), S(G)$ generate $N$ (which is in fact a semi-direct product of the two groups).

PART 2:   What sort of structure does the normalizer of $S(G)$ have?